# jersey (JSR-311), how to implement @POST in container pattern

Tags: java, rest, netbeans, jersey, jsr311

From NetBeans, I created a new REST webservice (using jersey), using the built-in wizards. in the container resource class, it created a stub,

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public Response postJson(Identity identity) {
    identities.addIdentity(identity);
    return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(identity).build();
}
```

how to i POST to this? my understanding is that in need to post name=val pairs. what's jersey expecting here? how would i post json to this using say curl? here's what i tried,

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA="{ \"id\": \"$1\", \"vcard\": \"$2\", \"location\": { \"latitude\": \"$3\", \"longitude\": \"$4\" } }"
echo "posting: $DATA"
HEADER='Content-Type:application/json'
URL='http://localhost:8080/contacthi-proximity-service/resources/is'
curl --data-binary "${DATA}" -H "${HEADER}" "${URL}"
```

when I post this, and look at the identity object coming in, all fields are null? I suspect my json is incorrect. when i manually add an object to my container, then form a get, I see this result,

```
{"identities":{"id":"Foo Bar","vcard":"VCARD123","location":{"latitude":"-1.0","longitude":"-1.0"}}}
```

when I try to post the same thing, all fields all null. I also tried,

```
{"id":"Foo Bar","vcard":"VCARD123","location":{"latitude":"-1.0","longitude":"-1.0"}}
```

same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send requests to this method using curl, you would have to use something like:

```
HEADER='--header Content-Type:application/json'
URL='http://localhost:<port>/methodName'
curl --data-binary request.json ${HEADER} ${URL} -D response.txt
```

You can pass a string to the method. Above code will pick json string from the file mentioned. Sample json could be:

```
{"userName":"test","timestamp":"2010-08-05T11:35:32.982-0800","userId":"0982"}
```

For creating response you can use something like:

```
return Response.status(Status.OK).entity(responseString).build();
```

Classes used are:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
```

Comment: i tried this, and editing the question accordingly. server does not seem to like that request. it never gets to my code.

Comment: try removing "-H" from the curl command, and post what are the results.

Comment: yeah i caught that, updated the q w/ the next issue. thanks. i'm suspecting that my json isn't formatted correctly. i'll update the question with that info.

Comment: okay.. well you should post your question after some homework to save duplicate effort for others. Last thing I would try is to remove double quotes around your variables in curl command.

Comment: the problem here ended up being how my model classes were jaxb annotated. this marked this as the answer so thanks for help, but this should probably be removed as the subject is misleading.